# how to print valus using for loop inside HTML table cell?

Tags: python, html, flask

My code is :

```
 <td>
    {% for i in value %}
    <input type='radio' value='{{i}}' name='radiobutt1' />{{i}}
                     <br><br>
     {% endfor %}
 </td>
```

The problem is that whatever is inside  is printed as such. Hence instead of printing the values it is printing the content inside  and  as such.
Here value has been returned by render_template in app.py file of flask.

Comment: What does this mean? What is "the content inside and as such"? Show an example of the output and explain how it differs from what you want.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly the problem is? What is the output you're getting and what's the expected output

Comment: I think the problem is `The problem is that whatever is inside is printed as such` means it is printing `value='{{i}}'` directly.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world(user=None):
    values = ["a", "b", "c"]
    return render_template('index.html', values=values)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`templates/index.html` file

```
<td>
    {% for i in value %}
    <input type='radio' value='{{ i }}' name='radiobutt1' />{{i}}
     {% endfor %}
 </td>

<table>
{% for i in value %}
<TR>
    <TD>{{ i }}</TD>
    <TD><input type='radio' value='{{ i }}' name='radiobutt1' />{{i}}</TD>

</TR>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't solve the problem because on running table cell is showing:{% for i in value %}
    <input type='radio' value="{{ i }}" name='radiobutt1' />{{i}}
                     <br><br>
     {% endfor %}

Comment: i.e it is not inferring it as a loop. It is even printing {% for i in value %} in table cell

Comment: @user9379120 Please have a look at the updated answer. If that doesn't help then you should try to provide more code in your question.

Comment: ya render_template is there in app.py and it is printing all the values inside the for loop if we display it simply on a web page . But, if I am trying to display inside a table cell then it is printing: {% for i in value %}
    <input type='radio' value='{{i}}' name='radiobutt1' />{{i}}
                     <br><br>
     {% endfor %}

Comment: For example if value is value=["this is good", "you are nice"] ...... Then in case of simply displaying it on web page it will display 1 radio button with value this is god and other radio button with you are nice. But in case of printing it inside table cell it is printing :{% for i in value %}
    <input type='radio' value='{{i}}' name='radiobutt1' />{{i}}
                     <br><br>
     {% endfor %}